# Python - Constructor without parameters in JSON module code

Tags: python, json

In Python's `json` module source code, I see:

```
def JSONObject(s_and_end, encoding, strict, scan_once, object_hook,
           object_pairs_hook, _w=WHITESPACE.match, _ws=WHITESPACE_STR):
        ...

def __init__(self, encoding=None, object_hook=None, parse_float=None,
        parse_int=None, parse_constant=None, strict=True,
        object_pairs_hook=None):
        ...
        self.parse_object = JSONObject
```

Are the arguments to `JSONObject` function being passed implicitely, or am I missing something ?

Comment: Could you make the title of this question more focused, for the sake of matching the question content? One edit I have in mind is "Constructor without parameters in JSON module code"--do you find this appropriate?

Comment: Done, thanks ! I was running out of ideas ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line `self.parse_object = JSONObject` isn't calling the function, so no parameters are necessary. Instead, `self.parse_object` is referring to the `JSONObject` function itself. Later code could then call the function by doing `json_obj = self.parse_object(param0, param1, ...)`.

Comment: Where is the JSONObject class defined ? I don't see it anywhere in the code.

Comment: @JahMyst it is a function. You included the first line of the definition in your question.

Comment: @JahMyst My mistake, edited answer to correctly say its a function rather than a class.

Comment: Thanks, I get it now.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the [`py_make_scanner()` function](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/json/scanner.py#l15):

```
def py_make_scanner(context):
    parse_object = context.parse_object

    # ...

    elif nextchar == '{':
        return parse_object((string, idx + 1), encoding, strict,
            _scan_once, object_hook, object_pairs_hook)
```

where `JSONDecoder()` instances are passed in as the `context`. So `context.parse_object` is `JSONDecoder().parse_object` is `JSONObject`, or if you so wish, a different callable, set by a subclass or by directly setting that attribute.

`py_make_scanner` is a pure Python implementation; there is also a [C implementation](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Modules/_json.c#l1767), and there is a C implementation for `parse_object` too ([`str` version](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Modules/_json.c#l857) and [`unicode` version](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Modules/_json.c#l984)).

To come full circle, the result of `make_scanner()` is then used again by the `JSONDecoder` instance; just a few lines below the `self.parse_object = JSONObject` line is:

```
self.scan_once = scanner.make_scanner(self)
```

and `self.scan_once` is used in `JSONDecoder.raw_decode()`.

Comment: I understand better now, but what does the name JSONObject refer to **at the moment it's called** ? If scanner.make_scanner is located after, it should throw a NameError, shouldn't it ?

Comment: @JahMyst Python names reference objects. `JSONObject` refers to a function object, created by the function definition you included the first line of in your question. A reference to that same function is then stored on the   `JSONDecoder()` instance as the `parse_object` attribute. The `make_scanner()` callable takes that attribute and stores a another reference to that function object in `parse_object`. The nested function `_scan_once()` uses the latter reference to *eventually* call the function.

Comment: @JahMyst `_scan_once()` is returned to the caller of `make_scanner()` and that reference is stored as the `JSONDecoder().scan_once()` attribute. So calling `JSONDecoder().scan_once()` can call the `JSONObject()` function because it has a reference to it. All this exists so that you can pass in a different callable if you want to change the behaviour of the decoder.

Comment: @JahMyst so in the end it doesn't matter what the name `JSONObject` refers to. That *name* is not being called anywhere. The `function` object it refers to is being called, yes. In theory you could assign something else to that name after creating a `JSONDecoder()` instance but that one instance will continue to work because it still has its own reference in the `scan_once()` function.